# Порты выделены на локальную сеть, или на каждое устройство?

Tags: сеть, порты, upnp

Понять не могу. В Upnp ты можешь подключиться к устройству зная только внешний ip и порт приложения. И я запутался. Портов вроде как 65535, но это порты на всю локальную сеть, или на каждое устройство по отдельности? Я не могу найти нормальную литературу, которая бы проясняло это(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На всю сеть. Роутер приняв запрос upnp выделяет свободные порты и сопоставляет их с портами клиента. В ответ говорит какой внешний адрес и порт удалось занять.

Comment: А если на 80 порте, который часто используется, запущен на 2х и более устройствах в одной локальной сети, то роутер на все устройства перекинет входящий запрос?

Comment: На одно. Второму устройству, если оно попросит, он даст связку портов внешний:81-внутренний:80